# Does spark-cassandra-connector support built-in load balanceing?

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I have Scala-based application and I need to connect it to Cassandra.
I found DataStax Enterprise drivers very useful in this regard, and those have a lot of cool features like in-built load balancing for Cassandra and that is really import for me.
Unfortunately there isn't any native DSE drivers for Scala. I know we can use DSE Java drivers, but in that case, we loose a lot of Scala cool features. 
I also found spark-cassandra-connector that's built by Datastax as well, but this built-in load balancing thing is really important to me and I don't know if spark-cassandra-connector support it or not.

In the Java-based applications using DSE Java driver, I need to config the built-in load balancer in a configuration file as below:

```
datastax-java-driver.basic.load-balancing-policy {
  class = DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy
}
```

I don't know the equivalent way in Scala using spark-cassandra-connector and I'm not even sure if it is possible or not.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Scala you can just use the Java driver - out of the box you don't have only support for base Scala types, but you can solve this problem by importing the [java-driver-scala-extras](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-scala-extras) into your project (as source code) - it works for at least for driver 3.x. Another issue is the support for `Option`, but this could done via Java's optional that has an [extra codec in Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#optional).

Regarding the customization of the driver - that part should work with Scala without change. Regarding the support of default policy in Spark - Spark Cassandra connector has a separate policy for a special reason - it's close to the Java's default policy, but with specifics for Spark.